# weird charecters ubuntu terminal after activate conda environment

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, anaconda, conda

I installed Anaconda in ubuntu 20.04,after I activate my environment
my conda prompt in ubuntu terminal is like this (env) [\e]0;\u@\h...
how should remove these weird characters?

Comment: Do you have a customized `PS1` variable (e.g., what does `echo "$PS1"` show)? What shell are you using (check with `echo "$SHELL"`)? Technically, you could disable PS1 editing with `conda config --set changeps1 false`, but then you lose the indicator (e.g., `(env)`) that shows what env is active.

Comment: my $PS1 show this:%(?:%{%}➜ :%{%}➜ ) %{$fg[cyan]%}%c%{$reset_color%} $(git_prompt_info)
I use zsh as shell